# Comparing Windows.Forms.ListViewItem Items for Uniqueness

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have a Windows.Forms.ListView where the user shall be able to add and remove entries. Particularly, those are files (with attributes) the user can pick through a dialog. Now, I want to check whether the file names / entries I get from the file picker are already in the list; in other words, there shall only be unique items in the ListView.

I could not find any way to compare ListViewItems to check whether the exact same entry and information is already present in my ListView. The only way I see now is to:

```
> Loop through the files I get from the picker (multiselect is true)
 > Loop through ListView.Items
   compare ListViewItem.Text
   > Loop through ListViewItem.SubItems
     compare .Text
```

If during the comparisons a complete match was found, the new entry is a duplicate and thus is not added afterwards.

This seems like an awful lot of effort to do something that I would find to be a function that is not so uncommon. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file system itself uses only the filename to test for uniqueness, so you should do the same, no need to compare sub-items too.

Comment: Uh, True! Saves me one for loop.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Items in a `ListView` typically represent some object. What I usually do is to assign that object (or at least some value identifying the object) to the [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tag.aspx) property of the corresponding `ListViewItem` when they are added to the list. That way you get a quite simple setup where you can compare items by getting the values from the `Tag` property and perform the comparison on those objects instead of the list view representation of them.

Comment: Thanks for the input.. However, like logicnp remarked, I actually already have a unique identifier in my ListViewItem - The full path of the files in my list. Mainly, I am looking for a way to not need to loop through the items myself - but I guess that doesn't exist. Anyway, in the meantime I implemented it with the for loops.